# Built-in Excel functions in a managed UDF for Excel Services

Tags: excel, sharepoint, service, user-defined-functions, managed

I’m thinking of moving a set of VBA functions to VB.Net with the objective using them to perform server-side calculations in Excel Services and Sharepoint. My understanding is that I need to create a managed UDF for this.

My question relates to the built-in Excel functions I’ve been using in VBA:

```
Application.Sum
Application.SumSq
Application.Count
Application.Average
Application.StDev
Application.Skew
Application.Kurt
Application.Min
Application.Max
Application.NormSInv
Application.TInv
Application.TTest
Application.VarP
Application.MDeterm
Application.MInverse
Application.MMult
Application.Transpose
Application.LinEst
Application.Index
Application.WorksheetFunction.RSq
Application.WorksheetFunction.Correl
```

Will Excel Services pick up on the fact these are native Excel functions? If so, what do I need to do in .Net to make Excel Services aware that these functions are native to Excel? Any worked examples would be greatly appreciated if this is possible.

Or would I be better of using .Net alternatives to these functions? If so, is there a source you can point me to which explains the mapping of native Excel functions to VB.Net functions?

Or am I forced to re-write these standard functions as custom functions?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
JK

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you should just be able to use XLApp.WorksheetFunction.fn (unless the functions are in the Analysis Toolpak which doing a quick scan of your list looks OK)

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for you response. Wouldn't I have to instantiate XLApp, i.e. create an instance of Excel in the background? I thought this wasn't possible with Excel Services.